# guildBanAdd can not read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to send a message to my audit logs every time someone gets banned from the server. This command works when someone joins the server, but it does not work when someone is banned, or unbanned.

This is the current code in the `index.js` file:

```js
bot.on('guildBanAdd', async (member) => {
  let channels = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync("././database/moderationChannel.json", "utf8")
  );
  
  let modchannel = channels[member.guild.id].channel;
  let modChannel = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === `${modchannel}`);

  modChannel.send(`${member} was banned!`);
});
```

What I want to happen is when the member is banned the message is sent to the `modCannel`. Is there anyway that this can happen?

Comment: The guildBanAdd-event comes with two parameters, where the first one is not member but guild: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Caramiriel mentioned in their comment, [`guildAddBan`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd) first parameter is the `guild` the ban occurred in and the second one is the `user` that was banned. There is no `member` parameter.

Another thing, as you store the channel IDs in the `moderationChannel.json` file. you can use `channels.cache.get()` instead of [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find). [`.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) should be preferred, as it gets an element with the specified key (the channel ID in this case).

You'll also need to replace `member` with `user` in `modChannel.send()` and check if `modChannel` exists. Check the snippet below:

```js
bot.on('guildBanAdd', async (guild, user) => {
  let channels = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('././database/moderationChannel.json', 'utf8')
  );
  let channelId = channels[guild.id].channel;
  let modChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId);

  if (!modChannel) {
    return console.log(`No moderation channel found with ID ${channelId}`);
  }

  modChannel.send(`${user} was banned!`);
});
```